# Add space between text and quotation in parskip

Tags: csquotes, parskip

I started writing my papre in the *thesis* class, with the *parskip* package. I've found a problem in spacing paragraphs: I want a very small space (still not 0 points) between main text paragraphs, but I find this space too small when it is between the main text and a quotation. How could I do it without changing my documentclass and staying in the *parskip* environment?

Answer (score 1):

The `quoting` package and its eponymous environment has a vertical spacing before and after the environment, controlled by the `vskip` key, which defaults to `topsep + partopsep`. Use `\quotingsetup{vskip= … }`. It also has a mechanism to control orphans within the environment and after it.